# Error Importing SHTOOLS Python Package

Tags: python, redhat

I am trying to import the spherical harmonic toolbox (SHTOOLS) in python. I have the files downloaded and unzipped and am using RedHat.

I added the package's path to my python system path and when I go to import the package, I get this error:

```
>>import pyshtools
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "pyshtools/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
     load_documentation()
 File "pyshtools/__init__.py", line 27, in load_documentation
     from . import _SHTOOLS
ImportError: cannot import name _SHTOOLS
```

I can not seem to figure out what the issue is. I checked that the path to this folder was actually added to the system path and it was.

Is this an issue on my end? Or is it possible that I have something downloaded incorrectly? If so, how would I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`SHTOOLS`](https://github.com/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS/) package needs to be built with `make` first to compile the Fortran libraries. The [wiki](https://github.com/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS/wiki) on Github gives directions on which libraries are required - `libblas-dev`, `liblapack-dev`, `g++`, `gfortran`, and `libfftw3-dev` (these are the Ubuntu packages, they may have slightly different names on Redhat). Once these are installed, you need to run `make`, then `sudo make all` to install the Fortran and Python components. The [`Makefile`](https://github.com/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS/blob/master/Makefile) has a lot of good comments in it, I'd recommend reading through it before running `make`.

Comment: That was definitely my issue. Thank you. I am new to Linux/RedHat, but I know I have Fortran 95 on here. When I try `make all` it told me that I did 
not have the dependencies downloaded. When I try `sudo yum install libblas-dev liblapack-dev g++ gfortran libfftw3-dev` it tells me that there is no package available and there is nothing to do. Are these not available for RedHat?

Comment: @Stellar you'll have to check out Redhat's RPM repo for the appropriate packages. I'm an Ubuntu guy, so sorry I can't give you exact package names.